# How to Design Jumpers to Connect a circuit and Disconnect another

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, schematics, jumper

I'm designing a PCB where I will use either a Micro SIM through a SIM card holder or an eSIM. I thought I would use a solder jumper to let the user select which SIM option to use, but I don't know how to design that. Is a jumper a good option in the first place in this case, or there are better practices for such issues?

Comment: Design alternative: There are sim card sockets with integrated switch. Use it to detect if a SIM is inserted and a mux IC to connect the proper data lines.

Comment: @asdfex would that be by connecting the switch as a selector of a 1x2 demux where the input is the VCC and one of the output to the SIM and the other to the eSIM? while keeping all of other data lines connected to each IC except the VCC of the deselected IC will be floating ?

Comment: This likely doesn't work. You often can't leave the data I/O of an unpowered chip connected. You need to switch the data line, which means you need to use a bi-directional switch.